# Font extension on jasper reports occurs flickering issues on browsers

Tags: jasper-reports

Could anyone help me to understand next behavior?

1. on server (Centos VM) installed font google-crosextra-

carlito-fonts.noarch (only this one contains necessary calibri font for my customer):

```
yum search calibri
google-crosextra-carlito-fonts.noarch : Sans-serif font metric-compatible with Calibri font

yum install google-crosextra-carlito-fonts.noarch
ls -l /usr/share/fonts/google-crosextra-carlito
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 816716 Sep 20 2013 Carlito-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 690516 Sep 20 2013 Carlito-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 623416 Sep 20 2013 Carlito-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 635996 Sep 20 2013 Carlito-Regular.ttf
```

"registered" new font in the system with command (but also reboot server):
`fc-cache -f -v`

2. created simple report on Jasper Studio with some text fields (Blank_A4.jrxml)
3. added font Carlito-Regular.ttf (from Centos server) to Studio (see screen)
4. exported Carlito-Regular.jar file from Carlito-Regular.ttf copied to WEB-INF/lib folder; restarted application server + removed all caches from /temp & /work
5. added to report font extension, saved it and published to Jasper server (JRS)

As result - on JRS it seems flickering problem with fonts during report execution. Please see screencast:
https://www.screencast.com/t/O3EH5FAE5n1L

Tried to apply a few different font to the report (Blank_A4_2 & Blank_A4_3 on video) as well as calibri.ttf downloaded from internet - the same result (on Chrome, Firefox, IE).
It looks like report is trying at first to load the some default font form OS and then the applied font of font family.

[image]